# 2-dim scalar PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I think this is a silly question, but nonetheless:

How does the solution of a two-dimensional scalar pde look like? Is this a function $u=(u_1,u_2)\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the PDE and when plotting this, we get a 3d-plot that looks "like a mountain", giving each tuple $(u_1(t),u_2(t))$ a real value?

In other words: The x-axis is $u_1(t)$, the y-axis is $u_2(t)$ and the z-axis is the image of the tuple $(u_1(t),u_2(t))\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Eh, what...? The tuple is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$, not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: And if the functions that you seek depend only on a single variable $t$, it's an ODE (or a system of ODEs, if you will), not a PDE.

Comment: Then, what is meant with 2-dim scalar PDE? Does this mean that a solution is a function $u\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\Omega$ being some subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes, most likely that's what is meant. But it's hard to say 100% sure without context.